# BeagleBone, OpenCV and webcam issue

Tags: opencv, camera, beagleboard, angstrom-linux

I've been trying to get [BeagleBone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone) work with [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) and a capture camera, but I couldn't manage to do it so far. I use [Logitech C270](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/hd-webcam-c270) webcam. Here is what I did so far:

1. I installed OpenCV binaries and tried my camera. Capture didn't work. I downloaded the latest version from Git and compiled it. Then it worked on my desktop.
2. Since [Ångström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) have pre-installed OpenCV, I directly tried to connect the webcam. But I had "select timeout" errors and when I saved the captured image, it was all black.
3. I deleted OpenCV from Ångström (`opkg remove opencv` and `opencv-dev`). It said it worked, but libraries were still in `/usr`. So I deleted them manually and copied libraries that I cross-compiled in my host. But now, I cannot even connect to camera. Capture returns null again.

I checked opkg list-installed, still OpenCV 2.4 is listed there. However, libraries in `/usr/lib` and include are the ones that I copied. How can I fix this problem?

Note: Webcam is recognized by Ångström, and [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) shows successful connection to the webcam.

Comment: Try downloading vlc using opkg and stream the video from camera. Does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems something was wrong on installation of Linux itself. I re-compiled the latest Ångström and installed it to BeagleBone. Everything worked fine as it should. It seems sometimes it's better to take the hard way.