# Why would my OpenCV program on BeagleBone Black capture images like this?

Tags: opencv, webcam, beagleboneblack, logitech

Here is a link to the type of images my program produces: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwVpO.jpg

I am trying out a simple capture test program that I have written. I am trying to capture images in a loop and save them onto the board properly numbered. The first capture sometimes is corrupted and the subsequent captures are a mix of two images. I have also observed that sometimes the upper half of the image is from the previous capture and the lower half is the capture from that cycle. I have given the details and the code below.

[OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) 2.4.2 running on [BeagleBone Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BeagleBoard#BeagleBone_Black) which has [Ångström](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m_distribution) installed on it.
The camera which is plugged to the USB of BeagleBone Black is Logitech C920.
The camera is connected to BeagleBone Black before power up through the 5 V power supply and connecting BeagleBone Black to the laptop. Access is through [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY).

#### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <cxcore.h>
#include "LaserWeed.h"
#include "SimpleGPIO.h"

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i=0, a;
    string name;
    int length;
    char c, Filename[10000];
    CvCapture* capture = NULL;
    IplImage* img = NULL;

    do
    {
        //I am not sure if this is necessary, but I tried anyway
        //to see if it makes a difference since upper half of
        //image was from previous cycle.
        capture = NULL;
        img = NULL;

        //Converting Numbers to string to save with proper name
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << i;
        name = ss.str();
        name = name + ".jpg";
        length = name.size();
        for(a=0; a<length; a++)
        {
            Filename[a] = name[a];
        }

        capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
        if (!capture)
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
            getchar();
            return -1;
        }
        img = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!img)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: img is null...\n");
            getchar();
            return -1;
        }

        cvSaveImage(Filename,img);
        cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
        cvReleaseImage(&img);

        i++;
        c = getchar();
    }
    while (c!='e')
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Where might I be going wrong?

The Stack Overflow question *[BeagleBone, OpenCV and webcam issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848045)* somewhat has a similar problem. But reinstallation of the OS will be my last option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird, anyway try to take the capture out of the do-while loop, maybe opening and releasing the capture device each time won't give enough time for the camera to prepare it's image buffers.

Comment: Sure. Camera initialization must be performed outside the loop. Depends on driver initialization (if camera will be reinitialized every time) but basically camera needs some time to get up and running.